# State custom type array var is not updated in init()

Tags: swiftui, state, init

I have following struct defined

```
struct ValuesPerCategory: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let categoryName: String
    let plan: Decimal
    let actual: Decimal
}
```

and then State var like this

```
@State private var values: [ValuesPerCategory]
```

in init() method of struct view I initialize values var in following way

```
init(/*some parameters*/) {
    var array = [ValuesPerCategory]()
    let objCategory = Category()
    if let categories = objCategory.getCategoriesByType(forType: categoryType, inContext: context) {
        let objValue = Value()
        for category in categories {
            let plan = objValue.getSummedValues(forCategoryID: category.id!, forValueType: .plan, forYear: year, inContext: context)
            let actual = objValue.getSummedValues(forCategoryID: category.id!, forValueType: .actual, forYear: year, inContext: context)
            array.append(ValuesPerCategory(id: category.id!, categoryName: category.name!, plan: plan, actual: actual))
        }
    }
    print(array.description)
    _values = State(initialValue: array)
}
```

All works fine for the first time when view appears but when init() is recalled because of some other state var updates values var is not updated even if array var is changed. Command "print(array.description)" shows different content than

```
Text(values.description)
```

in var body: View of the view struct.
Does anyone has a clue why? Above is working fully fine if state var is not custom array type.
Thanks.

Comment: You should watch Demystify SwiftUI  based on your description there is no reason for the view to be redrawn

Comment: show us your code where it does not work, or at least a simplified example that shows the `@State var values` not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way out - I created other vies struct and nested it in the original one. Then init started to work as expected.